# ionic - enable open a json file with ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngrx

I want to implement a restore data feature with an ionic 3 app.
The file is a simple json file (ngrx global state).

When user clicks on any json file, android and ios usually opens an actionsheet which allows the selection of apps and shortcuts (complete action with..)

Can anybody point me the correct plugin to use? In Android, if I open a json file, only some apps are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

- For android you can use the following cordova plugin: 
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-file-association
- Currently, there is no plugin which supports file association for
  iOS, but this can be achieved by extending the info.plist, see:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1
- The open the json file I recommand to use the following plugin (works both with iOS and android): https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2